# Parsing Flat Datafile for Read / Write

Tags: c#, database, parsing, flat-file, data-files

I need to connect to some old C-tree Plus database files from 1998. The product is discontinued by the vendor, but still used today in current releases of software. I need to be able to both read and write, but there is no ODBC type of connection available, only access to the files. Here is a sample of them:

http://64.72.211.216/zip.dat

http://64.72.211.216/zip.idx

Much of the content I need is stored as integers or strings, I can see it using a basic text editor, but there are also binary / UTF / HEX chars that are in the mix that would need to be filtered. There are no column names contained in the files.

I need to find a way to parse it to readable form like csv to read, and then reverse it to write.

There is no help available at all from the vendors involved, honestly I am not sure anyone at their companies know how it works after 20+ years since it was designed. I spent a good hour trying to convince the Faircom people to sell me the old ODBC without any support to no avail. While some documentation still exists, the ODBC library to utilize the documentation is unavailable.

I tried contacting Pervasive about their DataConnect, but evidently they phased out the parsing of flat files in their most recent version. They said in their old version it was based off of awk.

I found Progress.com's DataDirect to be interesting, but haven't gotten any calls back from them to see what is possible.

TextPipe Pro looks like it may work to read, but I don't think I could write with it.

Postgresql has the foreign data wrappers that will parse a CSV, I considered attempting to create a filter based off the CSV one for my data, but wasn't sure if that was a rabbit hole.

I am somewhat competent in C#, but am not sure where to start with this. My understanding is I need to define a "block size" that would represent one row, then transform what would be each fixed width column to ANSI from whatever it is now. Then export each row to a csv format that could be queried.

Please someone tell me there is a better way. Maybe a parsing library, utility, something at all that could be integrated into a C# application that runs on a schedule looking for updates.

Comment: So you are not wanting to change the app - it will continue to use this file in its current format, but you want external access to the same file - is that it? Or are you going able to replace the data engine with something else?

Comment: Is this the forerunner of ctree-Ace https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-treeACE ??? in which case there will be C/c++ and possibly  Delphi / .net interfaces. There may not be a SQL interface

Comment: Bruce, there are not ANY available .net interfaces. They were all commercial products that are no longer for sale. Tom, That is right. I am accessing customer's data which cannot be upgraded to a better format, I have to use it as is. I don't have access to the `data engine` as there are no ODBC drivers or other interfaces to utilize.

Comment: Do you have the DODA for the file? Without that, you're not going to be able to use most of the more recent FairCom tooling (they're embedded in the newer formats). I scanned the file in a hex editor and it doesn't look like it has any variable length string fields, so your best bet is likely going to be just reading out the raw binary into buffers (appears to be 65 bytes per record) and try to reverse engineer the field definitions. The header looks like it ends at 0x81.

Comment: The column definitions are contained in a DLL from the vendor that used Faircom C-Tree Plus to store their data. You are right about the length per record. I have about 100 tables to go through. Assuming I can properly parse them, if I change an INT value in a column (not ID) am I likely to have to update the .idx file? Will the .idx likely get auto updated from time to time from the server?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get pinged on your reply. I'm guessing that you wouldn't want to make any changes (updating the idx would be damned near impossible without a library). Does the 3rd party application have a re-index function?

Comment: I imagine they did, but I don't have any way of calling the function. I don't think it would matter based off of the columns that I'm planning on changing

Comment: One way to find out...  :-D  As long as you don't modify anything that's part of an index, you should be fine. Adding or removing records would be a no go.

Answer (score 0):

- which version was used to produce this idx/dat? is it a DOS/old Windows version? or Unix/Mac?
- try to get this version (it comes with full api/source) and a fitting compiler
- if you get the source you can recompile, add some header-wrappers to your C# project and use the C Dll (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9826/How-to-create-a-DLL-library-in-C-and-then-use-it-w)
- i know its old but then you can just read/write these types of file with the C api of c-tree (at least that can mean you need to use some old DOS/Windows compiler for testing)
- its THE most perfect start for analyzing the format 
  (see this tool: https://www.awportals.com/aw/archives/newsgroups/thread_468/)
- maybe Faircom still got the old version - tell em you need to find bugs in an old software that can't be replaced and the this library is missing - don't tell them you want to analyse the format
- or find an old reseller or people aorund the internet (google,reddit,stackoverflow) talking about c-tree and ask them if  they got a version for you "try to find C-Tree Plus Vx.y from 1988" is a good question on those platforms
- always relink between the other platform-post

Comment: You will have to do binary reads I think, do you have the file definition? This would contain the length of the header and then how long each record is